# WordPress broken app to try wpscan kali tool

Tags: wordpress, security, owasp, kali-linux

This is my first question.
I just learn how to use WPscan. "WordPress Security Scanner by the WPScan Team"
Does there any WordPress broken app to test what I've learned from WPscan?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find the target on vulnhub. For instance, DC2. You can download this and then install it on VMware, so you can access this target by LAN.

Comment: thank you so much. can you give me more details? Thanks

Comment: You can see the detail from this walkthrough.  https://medium.com/@ikuamike/hacking-dc-2-vulnhub-f65b8c58e419